# What does the C++ standard mean regarding object lifetime begins?

Tags: c++, standards, language-lawyer

In the n3690 C++ standard in section 3.8.1 there is this text:

```
The lifetime of an object of type T begins when:
— storage with the proper alignment and size for type T is obtained, and
— if the object has non-trivial initialization, its initialization is complete.
```

Assume that there is a user defined constructor.

What does the last sentence mean? Is it when the initializer list has finished initializing or is it when constructor body has finished running? Or does the last sentence mean something else?

Comment: It is when constructor body has finished running.

Comment: Ok, but how do you know that? I mean how can I read that the constructor body has finished running from ",its initialization is complete"?

Comment: It's complete at the next statement following the constructor call.

Comment: I am sure you are correct, but I am curious, how do you know this?

Comment: Are you asking where the standards says that running the constructor counts as initialisation?

Comment: @mantler As soon the next statement executes, you'll know ... As a side note: Don't confuse that with the assumption that construction of class instances is an atomic step in mutithreaded environments. It isnt!

Comment: @MrLister Yes, perhaps that is the question I am asking. But also how I can read that from that last sentence.

Comment: @g-makulik No, I have not assumed that.

Comment: 12.6 says how to initialize objects.  That may help you to see the trail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

12.6.2, [class.base.init], item 6, lists the steps of initialization, and this is the final one:

> Finally, the *compound-statement* of the constructor body is executed.

So once the body has executed, initialization is complete.

Comment: That whole section (in n3690 it was item 10) clarifies it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> when constructor body has finished running

This. An object that throws during construction is not guaranteed to have its invariants established, hence its lifetime doesn't start. A consequence of this is that the destructor will not get called:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Stillborn
{
    Stillborn()
    {
        std::cout << "inside constructor\n";
        throw 42;
    }

    ~Stillborn()
    {
        std::cout << "inside destructor\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        Stillborn x;
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "inside catch block\n";
    }
}
```

[live demo](http://ideone.com/a0wBNM). Note how "inside destructor" does not appear in the output.

Comment: How do you know this?

Comment: It's just common C++ knowledge I guess. May I suggest you put *Exceptional C++* under the Christmas tree? ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a note:

> "[ Note: initialization by a trivial copy/move constructor is
>   non-trivial initialization. — end note ]"

It means when the trivial constructor will finish its execution.

Comment: And you mean that this implies that the object lifetime begins when the copy/move ctor has finished? Or does the &rhs object lifetime begin inside the copy/move ctor?